# BGE shaking camera when i walk or run

Tags: game-engine, camera

I couldn't seem to find any videos on how to do this.
I'm making a game and I want it so when I walk or run the camera shakes.
how do I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an animation with the camera. Click this little red button in the timeline. [image: Automatic Keyframe Button](That inserts keyframes automatically when something is moved.) Select the camera, press alt + a to start the timeline, press g to grab it, and shake it around. press escape when you are finished. You can do this a much more sophisticated way, of course. :) Save your action. In the logic editor, use whatever sensor that causes you to run and link it to the action actuator also (where your camera is animated.) Remember to set the beginning and end keyframes to be where you had started and stopped the shaking. If you want a much more controllable way to do it, try using something from this video: https://youtu.be/PU_uhfO1Bsk

Hope that helps. ;) Tell me if you need more information. It would be a good idea to add more information to your question as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly what you are looking for , but it might be helpful. :D

Comment: I did what you said but I have a problem.  after the animation ends, it goes to the beginning. But in that split second the animation stops and looks really bad.

Comment: sorry it is really hard to explain

Comment: actully i might have fixed it. thank you for you help

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. No problem. ;)